# Timer issue in UpdatePanel Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer

i have an update panel with Timer, by defualt timer interval is 60 secs, I have 15 buttons on page, on each button click i want to assign timer interval 30 seconds, so each button click will give 30 seconds more until if not then timer_tick is called which will disable Timer and perform other works. Other buttons are not part of TimerUpdatePanel. On button clicks timer is not updating,  Please Advise. Thanks

My Aspx Code:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Timer ID="Timer2" runat="server" Enabled="False" Interval="60000" OnTick="Timer2_Tick"></asp:Timer>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatePanelTimer2" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer2" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <%--<p id="myTimer" runat="server" style="text-align: right; padding-right: 40px;"><%= Timer2.Interval.ToString() %></p>--%>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code behind Button_Click

```
int timer = 30;
Timer2.Interval = timer * 1000;
updatePanelTimer2.Update();
```

Code of Timer_Tick

```
protected void Timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Timer2.Enabled = false;
    Session.Clear();
    Session.Timeout = 1;
    Session.RemoveAll();
    Session.Abandon();
    Response.Redirect("~/TestPage.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved: 
i just had to add `<asp:Timer` under `ContentTemplate`.